# Why does my Url doesnt drop the current page instead it adds it with the new Link

Tags: .htaccess

Hi I have written an htaccess rule based on some sources but my problem is that I wanted it to have a clean url which I have done but the problem is it doesn't work well see image below
[image]
now I'm on the service page atmt now if I wanted to go to another page it will look like this
[image]

The url doesnt drop the 1st link but instead it goes to the next page adding the new link causing a Not Found Error..

I've been having a hard time finding solution for this one can someone please tell me where did I go wrong which rule on my htaccess is doing this?

here is my .htaccess

```
  RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/*(.*?)/index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/ [R=302,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/ [R=302,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^[^.]*?[^/.]$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=302]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^.]+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your rules look fine, but it looks like this is probably a relative URL issue. Your links probably look something like:

```
<a href="client">Client</a>
```

This means it'll append the `client` at the end of whatever URI path already exists (in your example, that would be `/services/`).

So either:

1. Change all your links so they start with a "/"
2. Add a relative URI base to the header of your page (inside the `<head> </head>` tags:

   ```
   <base href="/" />
   ```

Comment: I see will try this later.. Just a question though what do you mean on your suggestion #2? I dont quite get it can you elaborate it for me please?

Comment: @KimOliveros Add `<base href="/" />` tag somewhere inside your page header

Comment: ohh I see guess thats one more option then.  btw got it working by following your suggestion #1 marking this as an answer now :)